# Split layers by field QGIS version 3.2.3

Tags: qgis, layers, split-by-attribute

I want to split a vector layer based on values in a specific field.
In older versions I could use the plugins 'LayersbyField' or 'Split Vector Layer', but both seem not to be available anymore in version 3.2 of QGIS.

Are there quick and easy alternatives?
I don't like to 'select' and 'save as' for every value, since that takes too much time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now a tool in the processing Toolbox
[image]

Lots of thing have been added and/or moved in processing, remember to use the new search fonction (bottom left) to easily find anything